# What is the password to access Juju Web UI demo?

Tags: gui, juju

A demo of Juju Web UI is available at http://uistage.jujucharms.com:8080/
However, it asks for a password that is not mentioned in the blog or the development project of the UI.
I found the link to the demo in the following blog post:
http://www.jorgecastro.org/2012/10/16/announcing-the-juju-web-ui/

Many thanks
Adnene

Answer (score 2):

**The password to access Juju Web UI demo is ;**

```
Password : admin
```